# awk print a match only if last record before other match

Tags: awk

I want to use awk for printing a match of some pattern, only if it is the last line of the file before some constant text.

For example, i want to print the value of "c" only if it is the last line before some constant text:

```
cat file.txt:
a=1
b=2
c=3
...constant text...
```

print 3.

```
cat file.txt:
a=1
c=3
b=2
...constant text...
```

do not print anything.

How do I do that..? How can awk know if it's the last number of the file?

Comment: `awk -F'=' 'END{if ($1=="c") print $2}`

Comment: Nice. But I'll edit my question. I need to know what line number relative to the end of the file I am... Because if I add some conant test to the file, like a comment, this will not work.

Comment: @csny and how do you define "constant text"? What is a difference w.r.t. other lines in the file?

Comment: `'/...constant text.../{if (Prev[$1]=="c") print Prev[$2]}{split($0,Prev)}'`

Comment: _"I need to know what line number relative to the end of the file I am"_  That is not included in the sample output in the question.  Do you want to update the question with new requirements?

Comment: Constant text is a line or two, still not sure, but for example it might be a line that writes a status: "Slave/Master". But anyway, it will be constant format, that I'll need to know when awk is reading the last line before this constant format. @Costas your awk doesn't work

Comment: @csny This `awk -F'=' '/...constant text.../{if (Prev[1]=="c") print Prev[2]}{split($0,Prev)}'`?

Comment: @Costas This one works

Comment: @csny Your welcome. But the script almost same as in answer below.

Comment: @Costas it is pretty similar. Thanks anyway :) I posted an answer that gets it in a different approach

Answer (score 3):

> I want to use awk for printing a match of some pattern, only if it is
>   the last line of the file before some constant text.

In that case, try this:

```
awk -F= '/constant text/ && name=="c"{print value} {name=$1;value=$2}' file
```

#### Examples

```
$ cat file1 
a=1
b=2
c=3
...constant text...
$ awk -F= '/constant text/ && name=="c"{print value} {name=$1;value=$2}' file1
3
$ cat file2
a=1
c=3
b=2
...constant text...
$ awk -F= '/constant text/ && name=="c"{print value} {name=$1;value=$2}' file2
$
```

#### How it works

- `-F=`

  This tells `awk` to use `=` as the field separator.  In this way, we can separate the name and value for fields like `a=1` or `c=3`.
- `/constant text/ && name=="c"{print value}`

  If we reach a line with `constant text` and `name` (as last set on the previous line) is `c`, then print `value`.
- `name=$1;value=$2`

  For the current line, save the first field as `name` and the second field as `value`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using grep it has an option to print lines before match.

Option is : -B num, --before-context=num

In your case :

```
cat file.txt|grep -B 1 "constant text"|grep "c="|cut -f2 -d'='
```

Explanation :

1. Print just the line before constant text.
2. Filter all c values from output.
3. Extract second field with '=' delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Some googling found me the best answer so far, though I already got an answer: Using `tac` makes it much simpler...

`tac file | awk 'NR==2{if ( $1=="c") print $2}'`

The line number is one after the "constant text". If the "constant text" is one line - `NR==2`. If it is two lines - `NR==3`. Haven't decided yet what format the constant text should be...

Comment: To continue your decision I'd like to offer use `tail -n 2` instead of output reversing.

Comment: do you mean `tail -2 file | head -1` and test for "c=..."?

Comment: You are free to omit `head` by `awk 'NR==1'`

Comment: I actually tested for performance the two options:

`tail -2 ./test.txt | head -1 | grep "c=" | cut -d= -f2`
vs 
`tail -2 ./test.txt | awk -F'=' 'NR==1{if ( $1=="c") print $2}'. 
The `awk` one is faster. Surprised and impressed.

Comment: Check `tail -2 ./test.txt | grep -m1 -Po '^c=\K.*'` or `| sed -n '1{/^c=/s///p;q}'`

Comment: `grep -m1 -Po '^c=\K.*'` is the fastest. Guess its the `-Po` that makes it efficient?

Comment: Suppose no. I think the general reason in the command invocation ( call 2 programm is much faster then call 4 ones)

Comment: I mean it is faster than the `sed`. I know that `awk` is a heavy tool so the performance differance is expected. But why this `grep` is significantly faster than this `sed`